# mysql_result to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Below is the code, I have, it is written in mysql. My goal is to convert this to PDO.

```
$query = "SELECT name, age FROM table WHERE condition=$condtion";
$mysql_query = mysql_query($query);

echo $name = mysql_result($mysql_query, 0, 'name');
echo $age = mysql_result($mysql_query, 0, 'age');
```

I have tried doing the following code below, but it is giving me an empty result.

```
$query = $PDO -> prepare("SELECT name, age FROM table");
$query -> execute();

echo $name = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['name'];
echo $age = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['age'];
```

Comment: Try assigning the result of `$query->execute()` to a variable - what does that give you?

Comment: It gives me a result of '1'

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how you're using it?

Comment: What do you mean? that's my code above, there is nothing to edit.

Comment: So what is giving you a result of 1?

Comment: echo $name = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['name'];
echo $age = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['age']; never seen like this before. result may contain more than one result.

Comment: Note: each `fetch()` call fetches the next row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$query = $PDO->prepare("SELECT name, age FROM table WHERE condition = :param");
$query->bindParam(':param', $param); // define this somewhere
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch();

echo $name = $result['name'];
echo $age = $result['age'];
```

From PHP.net, fetch works as follows:
Fetches a row from a result set associated with a PDOStatement object. The fetch_style parameter determines how PDO returns the row.

When you execute a prepared statement, you need to perform a fetch or a fetchAll to pull the data. fetch gets you the first row, and in your case with a condition = X, I am guessing you only want one row.

Updated with links for reference:

execute: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

fetch: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: welcome to SO. +1 for the nice answer, just the links to `execute()` and `fetch()` function would make this perfect.